# Can't attach GlyphIcon to Textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm having real issues trying to get my bootstrap datepicker icon to attach to my textbox. I've read through all documentation and searched for hours to find a solution but nothing seems to work.

[image: This] is the closest i've gotten with my markup but the icon seems to align to the right hand side of the screen

```
<div  id="sandbox-container">DATE
    <div class="input-group date">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy to do with Bootstrap [input group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/input-group/) and [Font Awesome icons](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=calendar&m=free):

#### Structure

```html
<label for="xxx">Date</label>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="xxx">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Icon Choices

I am showing you the free version of Font Awesome Icons. You can use whatever you like to represent the date picker icon. Here is some: https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=calendar&m=free

#### Screenshots

[image]

#### Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/9a20fp3u/37/

Comment: These icons haven't helped unfortunately, they still appear on the other side of the screen. When I try your markup, the icon appears underneath the textbox as a small unclickable icon. Really don't know what it going wrong here.

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using? It seems like you're using version 3.

Comment: I've just upgraded to 4.5 as i'm in the infancy of my project and it solved the problem! Still having some issues here and there with the functionality but i'll work it out

Comment: @TomBennett: yeah I can tell you're still using one of the old versions because of `.input-group-addon' class, which has been deprecated. Glad it's working now.